# Dev c++ and allegro 5.0.x

Tags: c++, mingw, allegro, allegro5

I cannot manage to install Allegro 5 into Dev c++ 5.9 by Orwell or the original version on bloodshed.I install Dev C++ into the address already typed in(c drive) and then I used the built in devpak download and installer but whenever I try to compile the example program when I create a new Allegro 5 static project I get compile errors stating that all of the allegro include files cannot be found. I have tried everything over the course of 2 days in frustration, has anyone found a way to install Allegro 5 properly? Or is there an issue with the example code(doubtful).I am using 64 bit MinGW,Dev c++ 5.9 by orwell,and the default Mingw compiler and I checked if the linker included the files,and it did,I am also on windows 7 if it helps, and I ran as admin too,I do not understand what the issue could be.

Comment: You need to link the libraries (.a), and set the includes in project options. Then you need to include the proper header files.

Comment: Where are the .a files?I thought the Devpak did everything for you, even when I do a manual installation I cant compile ;/, is there anyway to download Dev c++ portable with allegro already installed? This is very frustrating, I have tried using code blocks too,to no avail, I don't think im doing anything wrong.

Comment: I use Orwell Dev C++, I am unsure of allegro. As far as libraries are, most every other compiler is .lib or whatever. The linker is probably giving you some trouble, find out (sort even,) and find the libraries file directory and add it. Eh, it's difficult to explain, but is pretty straight fowarad.

Comment: The dynamic versión of Allegro is personally easier to use, read the allegro docs to use the dynamic DLL instead of static linking.